# Powershell output column width

Tags: powershell, console

If I have an executable `out.exe` and it's `stdout` is redirected to a file,
i.e.:

`out.exe > $file`

Right now if I do this it only outputs:

```
<-----------------------------> 
80 columns per line to the file
```

Is there a way to make the standard output to be wider in console column count?
Is it the `out.exe` that's somehow messing with the columns?
In my case I'm using `fxcopcmd.exe`.

Comment: I want to update this question.  It turns out that im trying to output to Visual Studio Output window.. but the windows it wrapping at 80 charachters.. is there any way to set it to wider?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem a while back. Here's what I did to fix it:

```
# Update output buffer size to prevent clipping in Visual Studio output window.
if( $Host -and $Host.UI -and $Host.UI.RawUI ) {
  $rawUI = $Host.UI.RawUI
  $oldSize = $rawUI.BufferSize
  $typeName = $oldSize.GetType( ).FullName
  $newSize = New-Object $typeName (500, $oldSize.Height)
  $rawUI.BufferSize = $newSize
}
```

It simply sets a new width of 500 characters on the host's RawUI output buffer (though, since we run our build in several environments, and we did not want the script to fail just because it could not make the output a bit larger,  the code is rather defensive).

If you run in an environment that always sets RawUI (and most do), the code can be greatly simplified:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Size (500, 25)
```

Comment: Don't do this when calling a PowerShell from a Visual Studio build step.  It seems to hang PowerShell.exe .

Comment: Be careful when setting the size as setting one of the dimensions to a smaller value will cause the script to bork. This older blog post on the topic caused me some head-scratching - http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2008/12/09/powershell-output-capturing-and-text-wrapping-strange-quirks-solved.aspx#7718576 (FWIW my comment is near the bottom)

Comment: The single line solution worked when I wanted to read file names with directory paths in SQL Server via xp_commandshell.  No more wrapping at 80 characters!

Comment: I used the full solution in a TFS post-build script, for a build using the new TFS 2012 templates.  It worked exactly as advertised.  Thank you!

Comment: I lived with artificially wrapped log files for far too long. Thanks.

Comment: I was still seeing some wrapping with Verbose output in PowerShell run in Visual Studio Output window.

I was able to resolve by adding:  mode con cols=500;

Comment: I would like to know how this can be run every time I open up a powershell window so that I don't have to run it every single time?

Comment: @kkuilla Ask a new StackOverflow question :)  But I will tell you that you can do it by setting up your own [PowerShell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6)

Comment: The line `$typeName = $oldSize.GetType().FullName` really helped me! I was struggling with all other examples I found but checking the existing type made all the difference in my case (Powershell 5.0)

Answer (score 17):

Both the `out-file` and `out-string` cmdlets have a `width` parameter:

```
out.exe | out-file -width 132 -filePath $file
```

Comment: But this won't help if the exe is deciding to only output 80 characters.

Comment: out-file actually works, perhaps you have some out-string there ? then you have to also set its width

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old post at this point, but figured I'd throw my 2 cents in for people that stumble upon this for future use. From the sounds of it, OP is trying to increase the console window size so that lines do not wrap. My typical resolution I use to solve this:

```
$Width = $host.UI.RawUI.MaxPhysicalWindowSize.Width
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.size($Width,2000)
```

This should open up your output file so that wrapping is avoided and no conflict with -Stream (if being used) is created.

EDIT: This command is really only needed for older versions of PS (Below 7.1). Newest version should be able to get by with just -Width 500 after Out-String/File.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Windows PowerShell - just open "properties > Layout" increase buffer size + window size

[image]

Comment: which correspond to column width?

Comment: @Jaja The screen buffer size width is the number of character cells in each row. The larger the width size, the more text will show in the same row before wrapping.

Answer (score -1):

In my powershell script I set the first line to not do carriage returns
the second line I manually did a return.

(within a loop)

```
Write-Host -nonewline "$var1;$var2"

Write-Host "`r"
```

That overrode the issue with having my line wrapped but still doing a return after each individual record.

Comment: I believe the issue at hand is to increase the width of the output window in VS.... this doesn't seem like it answers the question properly.