# Width of PowerShell Output in the Visual Studio Output Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, powershell

I have a powershell script that runs fxcopcmd in the output window.  Turns out that when I output results it limits the output to 80 Chars, is there a way to get it to be wider in the visual studio output window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking my question a different way, and was solved directly: [Powershell output column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978777/powershell-output-column-width)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the ["solution"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347585.aspx):

> To get output that does not force line
>   wraps to match the screen width, you
>   can use the Width parameter to specify
>   line width. Because Width is a 32-bit
>   integer parameter, the maximum value
>   it can have is 2147483647. Type the
>   following to set the line width to
>   this maximum value:
>
> Get-Command | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\output.txt -Width 2147483647

Do not forget to use the `-Encoding utf8` switch to avoid creating binary dung.

Finally add a `type c:\temp\output.txt` to the PostBuild event to see your FxCop results.

Answer (score 0):

powershell's text output facilities usually have a -width option that controls how often they insert line breaks.