# Expand output of TF.exe results from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I converted a batch file to PowerShell that queried a TFS location to return the latest changesets and display them in a log file.  This is an edited version of that file:

```
function Get-TfsChangeset([string]$TfsPath, [int]$PreviousDays = 1)
{
    $TfExePath = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe"
    Write-Output "Getting history for '$TfsPath'..."
    Push-Location $LocalPath
    $Today = Get-Date
    $Prior = $Today.AddDays(-$PreviousDays)
    & "$TfExePath" history /recursive /format:brief /noprompt /version:D$($Prior.Month)/$($Prior.Day)/$($Prior.Year)~D$($Today.Month)/$($Today.Day)/$($Today.Year) $TfsPath
    Pop-Location
    Write-Output "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Done ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`n"
}

$ReportLogPath = "C:\temp\TfsHistoryReport.log"

Get-TfsChangeset "$/Some/Branch" > $ReportLogPath

Write-Output "Opening log '$ReportLogPath'..."
Start-Process notepad $ReportLogPath
```

However, the text returned from TF.EXE GET is cut off:

```
=========================== Started: 11/22/2011 09:43:31 =========================

Getting history for '$/Some/Branch'...
Changeset User          Date       Comment
--------- ------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------
12345     ...adis       11/21/2011 Invalid code in the tags.  Need to fix this
12346     joe.blow      11/21/2011 Bug#1: Nothing is working so fix it right n
12347     john.smith    11/21/2011 Bug#2: I don't like the new UI changes so f
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Done ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

=========================== Completed: 11/22/2011 09:43:42 =======================
```

I was able to get around it in the batch file by setting the console columns wide like this:

`mode con cols=250`

But I'm not sure how to do that in PowerShell.

Any ideas?

Comment: mode con cols=250 do the same thing in my powershell console..

Comment: I couldn't put that line it, I had to do a little extra, but that was the answer.

$originalBufferSize = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize
$newBufferSize = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size 250,$originalBufferSize.Height
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $newBufferSize
# TF.EXE stuff here
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $originalBufferSize

Comment: did you tried **BufferSize** property ?

Answer (score 0):

*From the OP's comment:*

I couldn't put `mode con cols=250` in, I had to do a little extra, but that was the answer.

```powershell
$oldBufferSize = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize
$newBufferSize = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.Size 250,$oldBufferSize.Height
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $newBufferSize
# TF.EXE stuff here
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $oldBufferSize
```

See also: [Powershell output column width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978777/2495)