# Why do the strings in my collection cut off words?

Tags: c#, powershell, collections, stringbuilder, ellipsis

I'm writing a PowerShell application specifically for Office 365 and I've come across a problem.

```
var result = pipeline.Invoke();
// close the runspace
runspace.Close();

// convert the script result into a single string

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.AppendLine("<----------------Results---------------->");
foreach (var item in result)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Now, everything works great until I get my results. The problem is that if I get a response like this:

```
UserPrincipalName          DisplayName                isLicensed                
-----------------          -----------                ----------                
johnsonadmin@johnsoncom... Jack M*****                False
```

If I run that same command in Powershell, I'll get the same results but with a little more organized formatting. Instead of saying "johnsonadmin@johnsoncom...", it will actually give me the entire email address.

I'm thinking this might be a problem with how collections automatically format my string, but I'm not sure. This becomes a huge problem when I'm trying to parse that text for email addresses ;)

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978777/powershell-output-column-width help ?

Comment: What are the types of objects involved ? PowerShell does some groovy things with representation, but you are just calling ToString(), falling back to the C# ToString implementation for that particular object. That _could_ be the problem. (Also look at the link posted in another comment).

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to parse the results of a pipeline as a string, you're completely missing the *raison d'etre* of powershell: **you don't have to parse strings**. That's so Jan 1, 1970. Awk, sed and grep are in a retirement home in Florida when you sit in front of a modern Windows machine these days. If you feel yourself reaching for Cygwin, you're doing it wrong.

I'm doing this off the top of my head taking your script as a starting point, but you'll get the point (I hope):

```
//...
// result is a Collection<PSObject>
foreach (PSObject item in result) 
{ 
     // properties are not case-sensitive
     string userPrincipalName = item.Properties["userprincipalname"].Value as string;
     string displayName = item.Properties["displayname"].Value as string;
     bool isLicensed = item.Properties["islicensed"].Value as bool;
     // ...
}
```

Geddit? Btw, the reason you're seeing everything cut off in the output is that you're capturing the display-friendly formatted output which is optimized for a narrow console window.

Comment: I really just started doing Powershell stuff in C# so I had no idea I could just get property information out of the PSObject. That's super cool! However, I'm now having an Object reference not set to instance of an object... I've been through Google to make sure userprincipalname is the right property. Not sure where to go from here other than continuing to research (which I will do.)

Thanks for the help, by the way! I've been out of the programming scene off and on for a while and my knowledge is fairly limited.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item.ToString()`, access the actual properties.

Comment: Here's what I have that is giving me the object reference error:

`string userprincipalname = item.Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value as string();`

I don't know if it matters, but I have the entire thing as an "AddScript" instead of an "AddCommand". Regardless, if I do item.ToString(), I get the results I got from my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help on the whole properties piece - I had no idea I could do that.

My most recent problem, however was in the object reference issue. I ended up resolving that by using [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/1cc88c15-7b9e-45b9-bc98-eeb6d4bbbfaf).

In combination with using a different type of Powershell so I could invoke twice and connecting to the MSOnline service through ISS, I was able to get my list of users without parsing text :)