# powershell select-string -pattern crlf issues

Tags: powershell

Does powershell have a default line length that it will output before it starts a new line automatically? I'm seeing extra CRLF in my output file where they shouldn't be (ie. the input file is a csv file with crlf at the end of each line, but after doing a -pattern the result file is splitting each line up into multiple lines and each line seems to be the same max size)

Answer (score 1):

From my powershell profile (replace 500 by something that suits you):

```
# Dynamically change the host buffer width because some cmdlets specifically
# rely on it and truncate information that exceeds the initial limit (80 characters).

if ($Host -and $Host.UI -and $Host.UI.RawUI) 
{
    $rawUI = $Host.UI.RawUI
    $oldSize = $rawUI.BufferSize
    $typeName = $oldSize.GetType().FullName
    $newSize = New-Object $typeName (500, $oldSize.Height)
    $rawUI.BufferSize = $newSize
}
```

Comment: It seems you copied the code here from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1165347/237838), which Hyper Anthony marked as a possible duplicate. If you do such a copy you should 1) link to your source and 2) include other content in your own words explaining it.