# Why does shell_exec adds unwanted break lines into my output?

Tags: php, wmi

I am trying to run the following line in php

```
$task_list_raw = shell_exec('PowerShell.exe -Command "Get-WmiObject -Query \'SELECT * FROM Win32_Process\' | Format-List -Property ProcessId, Name, CommandLine"');
```

If i'm running the same command in PowerShell without the esacaping backslashes, then i get the following output **in a single line**:

CommandLine : PowerShell.exe -Command "Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_Process' | Format-List -Property ProcessId, Name, CommandLine"

Meanwhile my $task_list_raw contains the same data with some unwanted line breaks. Without the escaping characters it always puts a line break after a certain character length. Can someone explain me why is this happening?

The php's version on the computer is really old (5.4.24). Can this cause problems like this or it may be something else?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978777/powershell-output-column-width answer this?

Comment: Not really, but it gave me an idea to change my approach from Format-List to Format-Table, this way i could use -AutoSize on my table, so everything is in their right place but it kinda makes it harder to split by column.

Comment: Use `Select-Object` instead of  any of `Format-` cmdlets.